# Infinite Scroll and Stash

Tags: stash, pagination

Anyone have luck in getting the [Stash-style of pagination](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Capturing-pagination) to work with [Infinite Scroll](http://iamjustinlong.com/blog/single/implementing_infinite_scroll_in_your_expressionengine_site/)? Is it possible?

Comment: You got it! Answer posted below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Got it working. This is what I have for those following:

**set_list template**:

```
{stash:embed:layouts:homepage}

{exp:stash:context name="100_list"}

{exp:stash:set_list
    name="movie_list"
    context="@"
    parse_tags="yes"
    save="yes" 
    scope="site"
    refresh="1440"   
    replace="no"
}

    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="films"
        category="1"
        disable="category_fields|member_data"
    }

        {stash:movie_name}{title}{/stash:movie_name}
        {stash:movie_url}{url_title_path='movie'}{/stash:movie_url}
        {stash:movie_poster}{exp:channel_images:images entry_id="{entry_id}" limit="1"}{image:url:grid}{/exp:channel_images:images}{/stash:movie_poster}

    {/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

**homepage embed with get_list:**

```
<ul class="large-block-grid-5 grid-infinite">

{exp:stash:get_list
    name="movie_list"
    context="@"
    parse_tags="yes" 
    parse_conditionals="yes"
    limit="20"
    orderby="movie_name"
    sort="asc"
    paginate="bottom"
}
    <li class="grid-item-block">

        <a href="{movie_url}" title="{movie_name}">
            <div class="grid-item-info">
                <div class="grid-item-title">
                    <h1 class="title-cap">{movie_name}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>      
                <img src="{movie_poster}" alt="{movie_name}">       
        </a>

    </li>

    {paginate}
    <div class="navigation">
        {if next_page}<a class="next js_hide_next" href="{auto_path}">Next Page</a>{/if}
    </div>
    {/paginate}

{/exp:stash:get_list}

</ul>
```

**javascript settings:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.grid-infinite').infinitescroll({
          navSelector : ".navigation",
          nextSelector : "a.next",
          itemSelector : ".grid-item-block",
          contentSelector: ".grid-infinite",
          extractLink: true,
      })
    });
</script>
```